# What is the benefit of using Futures over parallel collections in scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, actor

Is there a good reason for the added complexity of Futures (vs parallel collections) when processing a list of items in parallel?

```
List(...).par.foreach(x=>longRunningAction(x))
```

vs

```
Future.traverse(List(...)) (x=>Future(longRunningAction(x)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the main advantage would be that you can access the results of each future as soon as it is computed, while you would have to wait for the whole computation to be done with a parallel collection. A disadvantage might be that you end up creating lots of futures. If you later end up calling Future.sequence, there really is no advantage.

Comment: I think that the `foreach` used the author of the question is not very good use case for parallel collection. The really useful aspect of parallel collections is when using folds and reduces.

Comment: I interpreted the question a bit more broadly. I think that is just one example out of many possible uses.

Comment: @pedrofurla I understood the usefulness of parallel collections with folds and reduces, but what about flatMap and map ?

Comment: @KimStebel IMO it's a bit harder to customize the underlying threadpool with parallel collections, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Futures become useful as soon as you want to compose your deferred / concurrent computations. Futures (the good kind, anyway, such as Akka's) are monadic and hence allow you to build arbitrarily complex computational structures with all the concurrency and synchronization handled properly by the Futures library.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel collections will kill of some threads as we get closer to processing all items. So last few items might be processed by single thread.
Please see my question for more details on this behavior [Using ThreadPoolTaskSupport as tasksupport for parallel collections in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703332/using-threadpooltasksupport-as-tasksupport-for-parallel-collections-in-scala)

Future does no such thing, and all your threads are in use until all objects are processed. Hence unless your tasks are so small that you dont care about loss of parallelism for last few tasks and you are using huge number of threads, which have to killed of as soon as possible, Futures are better.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: @double-beep Added 2nd para to tailor the answer to this question.

Comment: Neither parallel collections nor futures are killing any threads. They are both using threads from an execution context, which may be backed by Thread Joint Pool or Thread Pool - those pools keep the threads ready for tasks. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html